# React - Adding component in Map function not adding

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary

I want to add components into the dom through using the map function over an array.
`{books.map((book) => <Book/>)}`

However, it is not adding anything, it is as if the books array is empty?
I printed books using `{console.log(books)}` and it is non empty. What is wrong here? I have attached my render function.

```
  render() {
    let books = this.state.books;
    return (<div className="bookshelf">
      <h2 className="bookshelf-title">{this.titles[this.props.shelf]}</h2>
      <div className="bookshelf-books">
        <ol className="books-grid">
          {books.map((book) => <Book/>)}
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>)
  }
```

For anyone's info, I obtain the values of book through an api call.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    BooksAPI.getAll().then((books) => {
      books.forEach((book) => {
        if (this.state.shelf === book.shelf){
          // console.log(book);
          this.state.books.push(book);
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

Thank you if you understand what is going on.

Comment: probably the API call hasn't returned and you're using the books array. Can you provide more information, like whole file?

Comment: @Ajay Gaur Hi Ajay, the problem has been resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whats wrong is that you are `directly mutating` the state and it doesn't re-render so the change is not reflected in your DOM. use `setState` to update state

```
componentWillMount() {
    BooksAPI.getAll().then((books) => {
      const tempBooks = [];
      books.forEach((book) => {
        if (this.state.shelf === book.shelf){
          // console.log(book);
          tempBooks.push(book);
        }
      })
      this.setState(prevState => ({books: [...prevState.books, ...tempBooks]}))
    })
  }
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I realised I should not directly  mutate the state!

Comment: kindly dont demand for an acceptance of answer. Why are you so impatient?

Comment: This method is wrong, you do are adding an array into an array

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Doesnt matter, I have answered my own question

Comment: Your answer is actually more inefficient

Comment: Well in that answer, you are doing setState in a loop, that will trigger re-render as many times as the contents in the loop which is highly inefficient

Comment: However, take note of your variable declaration, theres a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

```
render() {
    let books = this.state.books;
    return (<div className="bookshelf">
      <h2 className="bookshelf-title">{this.titles[this.props.shelf]}</h2>
      <div className="bookshelf-books">
        <ol className="books-grid">
          {books.map((book) => return(<Book/>))}
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>)
  }
```

Comment: No need of return if its a single line statement,

Comment: No need to use return

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct fix. I want to add the book into the previous array.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    BooksAPI.getAll().then((books) => {
      books.forEach((book) => {
        if (this.state.shelf === book.shelf) {
          this.setState(prevState => ({books: [...prevState.books, book]}))
        }
      })
    })
  }
```